# $\lim(a_n+b_n)$ for $\lim a_n, b_n = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So I know that if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent series then,

$$\lim(a_n+b_n)=\lim a_n+\lim b_n=a+b$$

however, in case of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n= \infty$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_n= \infty$,
this clearly does not hold anymore and I think need to prove  that

$$\lim(a_n b_n)=\infty$$

$$\lim(a_n + b_n) = \infty$$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (c a_n)=...$
I think in the here it depends on the sign of $c$ and it would either be $\infty$ or $-\infty$?

I tried to prove it with M-N, so for the first one let $M, N > 0$, then we have a $n>n_1$, such that $a_n > M/N$, and we have a $n_2>0$, such that $b_n > N$, can I just say that $a_n b_n$ > M? and then I would be finished?

Could someone help me with the other cases?

Comment: for addition, only one sequence needs to diverge for their sum to diverge. this is not true in general for multiplication of two sequences (see stolz-cesaro theorem) and for the last one, yes it does depend on the sign of $c$. in your proof attempt, what is $B$?

Comment: @CSquared: Thank you for the answer, the B was a typo, I meant N. I have looked up the Stolz-Cesaro theorem, but I can not find where it says that $\lim(a_n b_n)$ does not need to equal $\infty$. What would a counter example for that case be?

Comment: i believe i misspoke on the multiplication. i was thinking of $\infty/\infty$ cases, but you are right. multiplication of two divergent sequences is divergent. otherwise your proof attempt looks fine to me

Comment: for the sum of divergent sequences, let $M>0$. Then there is an $n_1$ such that $a_n>M/2$ for $n\geq n_1$ and there is an $n_2$ so that $b_n>M/2$ for $n\geq n_2$. see what you can do from there.  the last case with the constant should be relatively easy if you work through the definition of $a_n$ being divergent.

Comment: @CSquared: Thank you for your help. So in the last case , we know that there is a $M > 0$ such that $a_n > M$ for a $n_1$, and for $c > 0$ $c*a_n > M$ and for $c<0$, then $c*a_n < M$ ?

Comment: sorry for late reply, but yes. I would say that the $c=0$ case is trivial. given $c>0$, you have $a_n>M/c$ for all $n\geq n_1$  which implies $ca_n>M$. If $c<0$, then we have $a_n>-M/c>0$ for all $n\geq n_1$ so $ca_n<-M$ which implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}ca_n=-\infty$